# How can i get the base reserve for stellar?

Tags: stellar-sdk

currently in ripple when i need to check how much is the minimum required to keep account valid there is a property called reserve base XRP
is there something similar in stellar? because to write hard coded 1 XML is not what i am looking for. so i guess there must be a way to figure what is the minimum that requires to keep an account valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you query the `/accounts/{account_id}` endpoint, the `subentry_count` will tell you how many sub entries the account has.

The reserve is `basereserve * (2 + subentry_count)`

Comment: i am still do not know how to get the "basereserve" for this equation - this as my main question. what is the way to get it?

Comment: I might link it again... https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#minimum-account-balance :)

Comment: the basereserve is included in the ledger headers. Using the JS SDK, `const ledger = await server.ledgers().order('desc').limit(1).call();`, then get either `base_reserve` or `base_reserve_in_stroops`

Comment: so, it does not always return same response? i mean 1 ledger can give base_reserve_in_stroops and the other base_reserve?
and 100000000 in stroops is 1 xlm?
btw, Synesso - i only now saw the link at the bottom of the page reffers to the param.

Comment: The property name depends on the protocol version. I don't remember when it changed. I check for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

The [minimum account balance](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#minimum-account-balance) is a function of the number of entries on the account.

Every account needs 2 x base reserve. Then an additional 1 base reserve for every *entry*. Entries include:

- Trustlines
- Offers
- Signers; and
- Data Entries

See [minimum account balance](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#minimum-account-balance) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As Johan pointed out, you can find the base reserve or minimum balance required for a stellar account from subentry_count. Here is an example in Javascript.

```
const base_reserve = 0.5
basic.minbalance = function minbalance(req, result)
{
    StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();
    server.accounts().accountId(req.query.PublicKey).call()
                .then(function (accountResult)
                {
                    var asset_count = accountResult.subentry_count;
                    var min_balance = ((2 + asset_count) * base_reserve);

                     result(null,
                    {
                        "count": asset_count, // gives number of assets with trustline
                        "min_balance": min_balance,

                    });
                });
  }
```

This is just a sample, ensure you have imported stellar-sdk,